# Using php in html does not work, WHY?

Tags: php, mysql, html

I am trying to get connection to a local database, but I have big problem.
I am using notepad++

It doesnt understand the `<?php` it seems..
Not even Hello world is printed out. I dont understand why?? Someone please help!?

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
</HEAD> 
<BODY>

    <?php

        echo 'Hello World';
        $con = mysql_connect("localhost:3306","user","password");
        if(!$con){
            die("Cant connect: " . mysql_error());
        }

        mysql_select_db("mysql_projekt",$con);
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM artiklar";
        $myData = mysql_query($sql,$con);

        while($record = mysql_fetch_array($myData)){

            echo $record['titel'];
        }

        mysql_close($con);
    ?>

</BODY>
```

Comment: What's the filename? It'll need to be .php for the above to work.

Comment: your document is a .php? or .html? Because it must be a .php to use php

Comment: Looks like Apache isn't configured to parse the PHP or you don't have PHP installed on the server. have you installed one of the common WAMP/LAMP flavours of the bunch?

Comment: which extension you are using for saving this page?

Comment: I agree with @Fluffeh.  It sounds like the server is not compiling the PHP.  Remember that PHP is a server-side scripting language.  A web browser alone cannot translate it.

Comment: may be your server is not started....

Comment: @AlessandroMinoccheri `it must be a .php to use php` is incorrect. All you need to do is add `AddType application/x-httpd-php .html` to the .htaccess file for Apache to parse a .html as PHP. This may or may not be a security issue, however.

Comment: if it doesn't show *anything*, even when you view source, then you have another issue.  Try the following in your `<body>` tag;  `Hello <?PHP echo 'world'; ?>!` while commenting out or removing everything else.  Then see what is displayed.

Comment: if it is ended with .php, then paste error or warning you are getting on page

Comment: Yes thats the problem. It doesn´t show anything. The page is just white with nothing on it

Comment: rename your file to index.php, be carefull not to over write another file

Comment: It just display Hello. Not world

Comment: Do you open the page from within your server (localhost OR remote server)?

Comment: does it show anything when you **view the source of the page?**

Comment: can you check error_log file ? it will help us

Comment: My random guess is that the OP doesn't even have a webserver.

Comment: he did a research, even tryed, he does not deserve a -1

Comment: If it shows nothing it looks like he IS using server, but with either error_reporting set to none (and e.g. mysql is not running) or server is misconfigured and errors are not shown

Comment: Since you're just getting started with PHP, please **DO NOT** learn the deprecated `mysql_query` interface. If not used *perfectly* you will have very serious [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/php) in your application. It takes all of thirty minutes to learn how to use the newer interfaces and it will save you hours and hours of headaches later.

Answer (score 1):

For PHP to work, you need to run it from a server - you can't just open it up in a browser like you can with an HTML file. Your file needs a .php extension, and you need to make sure your server is set up to use PHP. Windows does not come with Apache, PHP or MySQL pre-installed.

PHP is a preprocessor: the server parses the PHP code and uses that to output HTML, which is then interpreted by your browser. Without a server, the PHP can't be parsed and is fed to the browser as invalid HTML instead.

If you're on a PC, try [AppServ](http://www.appservnetwork.com/) for a local PHP/Apache/MySQL installation. If you're on a Mac, try [MAMP](http://www.mamp.info/en/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

A good Windows PHP testing environment is [WAMP](http://www.wampserver.com)

Answer (score 0):

1 install a web server, like wamp under windows or lamp undex unix

2 turn the web server on and access the phpmyadmin in order to create the database: `http://localhost/phpmyadmin`

user should be root, is asked

now, just create the database

3 go in `c:\wamp\www\` and create a folder; now create a file index.php, and write your code there and save the file

4 access the webpage like `http://localhost/the_path_used_by_you/index.php`

index.php might be missing, because the apache web server searches for index.php or index.html  or index.htm file

Comment: It may have improved over the years, but for a long time XAMPP was a much higher quality product than WAMP.

Comment: true, wamp is used now ... because of the easy config and menus

Answer (score 0):

re: `It just display Hello. Not world`

view source after having the body just display the `Hello <?PHP echo 'world'; ?>!` in the body.

If it shows your PHP code in there, then you are looking at ensuring that the .php extension is being parsed by the server correctly, and/or setting up your server to parse all .htm/.html files as well.  See the other comments as they point this out as well.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the server locally on your computer you will have to modify the /etc/httpd.conf or better make an .htaccess containing the command below (i think)

You have to add the line `AddType application/x-httpd-php .html` .
This is for apache to parse .html files and see if they include php.
Otherwise if you save you file with .html extension then the php parser won't check it for php code.